# Status call back URL in twilio

Tags: twilio

I want to get the status of my call while using twilio.
I am configuring a status call back url for the same which is accepting a Post verb. But not sure What should the method of the REST webservices have in its POST method? If Twilio is posting back the status, then what should the POST method of the webservices do? Not able to get a idea on this, please help..
I am programming it in .net

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The status callback requests will send [all the regular parameters that any Twilio Voice webhook sends](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#synchronous) as well as a [few extra parameters that you can find in the documentation here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/voice/making-calls#statuscallback-parameter).

Comment: Can you please provide a sample code what should be written in my verb service. I have done all coding in c# language. Your help will be great

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far and what information you are trying to get from the status callback?

Comment: I have a made a service which is accepting a post method

Comment: var fullUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "POST") { var CallSid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["CallSid"].ToString(); var CallStatus =HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["CallStatus"].ToString(); var To = HttpContext.Current.Request.Params["To"].ToString();
 }

Comment: That's not an awful lot of help. Could you update your question, it is hard to read code in comments, and also explain what results you are getting and what you want to achieve? Have you taken a look at [this example](https://www.twilio.com/docs/guides/how-to-confirm-delivery-in-csharp#getting-status-events-for-twiml-generated-messages)? It's about SMS, but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution how to get back status from twilio. Just design an Http Handler and use the context property to get back the parameters. The handler should look like this:

```
 Public Sub ProcessRequest(ByVal context As HttpContext) Implements IHttpHandler.ProcessRequest
    Dim callsid = context.Request.Params.Get("CallSid")
    Dim FromNumber = context.Request.Params.Get("From")
    Dim ToNumber = context.Request.Params.Get("To")
    Dim callStatus = context.Request.Params.Get("CallStatus")

    ' ...
 End Sub
```